# How can I backup someone else's Twitter account or Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, twitter, facebook-pages, backup, online-backup

How can I backup the tweets of an account that does not belong to me or the posts of a public Facebook page? All backup services I found on the web require authentication of the Twitter account (username and password).

Comment: What would you need to be able to do with the backup file?   Usually a "backup" is something that you can use to recover if something goes wrong, but I don't see how that would apply in this case.

Comment: Choose one of the services please and edit. The question as it stands is too broad. The API for Twitter is not the same as Facebook.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ The tweets/posts of some people are very informative and it can be uneasy to browse through thousands of tweets/posts on the twitter/facebook page. Suppose that someone tries to write the history of an Arab Spring revolution and wants to browse through the posts/tweets of the activists two years ago!

Comment: So what you want to do is not "back up" at all.   You want to extract a feed of a given user's tweets over time, and read them in one stream that is not interrupted by anyone else's Tweets.    There are various people who have done research on the contents of Tweets, presumably they had access to such software.  Perhaps you should google for topics like this.

Answer (score 5):

Backing up someone else's data without consent may violate TOS or laws of state you or they reside in.

Visit this information before trying to acquire someone else's data:

- [Ethics of Online Backup Systems](http://www.americanbar.org/groups/departments_offices/legal_technology_resources/resources/charts_fyis/OBSethicsfyi.html)
- [Facebook TOS](http://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)
- [Twitter TOS](http://twitter.com/tos)